# Drop CC Recipients

Tags: email, exchange-2010

I'm looking for a way to automatically drop any CC'd recipients when users send to a specific email. It needs to happen silently before the email reaches the destination. Running Exchange 2010.

Does anyone know of a method to achieve this?

Trying to prevent people from CCing our helpdesk, which is causing problems with duplicate tickets.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [Transport Rule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj657505(v=exchg.150).aspx) that matches emails where your helpdesk is CC'ed and then applies the "[RemoveHeader](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998315(v=exchg.150).aspx)" action to remove the "Cc" field.

Comment: Ooh - nice catch. I didn't realize RemoveHeader would operate on anything besides X-headers

Comment: Looking through, I'm not seeing a way to do this other than recreating the header?

Answer (score 0):

/Edit - GTirloni's answer seems correct and mine seems incorrect. I'm leaving mine up as an example of something that won't work.

There isn't any way to do this using native tools in Exchange, like Transport Rules.

You can probably make a rule for the conditions

1. To: field matches "desired primary address"
2. cc: field matches any "*" (maybe, not sure if this needs to be a named recipient)

with the action

3. Delete message

But it will delete the message to the recipient, as well.

There may be 3rd-party tools that can do this kind of mangling. In your case, your most effective path may be in the business logic of the helpdesk ticketing application, if it's configurable enough.

Comment: Edited your question and my answer with your new info.